# Get all records based on Date Range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I want to query below table data based on Date Range.

```
Id      | DateFrom    |  DateTo
--------+-------------+-------------
1       | 2019-09-15  |  2019-09-17
2       | 2019-09-20  |  2019-09-20
3       | 2019-09-21  |  2019-09-21
4       | 2019-09-22  |  2019-09-22
5       | 2019-09-20  |  2019-09-22
```

I wrote this query to filter data and I'm not getting any data.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime = '09/02/2019' -- MM/DD/YYYY
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime = '09/20/2019'

SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE (@StartDate BETWEEN DateFrom AND DateTo) 
   OR (@EndDate BETWEEN DateFrom AND DateTo)
```

The output should be 1, 4, 5 records.

If `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` are `'09/21/2019'`, then the output should be 3, 5.

Comment: Your code works fine: dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3f3944a27d07e00208310e0e7cfa53a3

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3aa7a98cad91a647478260c50e9da2c8, works fine!

Answer (score 0):

You are relying on database session settings here. Is '09/02/2019' February 2 or September 9? Does the setting allow '/' to be a date part separator? Better use an unambiguous format. That is `'YYYYMMDD'`  for all SQL Server versions (or `'YYYY-MM-DD'` for newer ones).

Then, what type are your date columns? If they are datetimes actually, there may be time parts you don't see. You can cast to date to play safe.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime = '2019-09-02'
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime = '2019-09-20'

SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE (@StartDate BETWEEN CAST(DateFrom AS DATE) AND CAST(DateTo AS DATE)) 
   OR (@EndDate BETWEEN CAST(DateFrom AS DATE) AND CAST(DateTo AS DATE));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Below query serve my purpose. However, below query returns duplicates.. and handled distinct in c#.

SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE (DateFrom BETWEEN ''' + @DateFrom + ''' AND ''' + @DateTo + ''') 
  OR (DateTo BETWEEN ''' + @DateFrom + ''' AND ''' + @DateTo + ''')
  OR (''' + @DateFrom + ''' BETWEEN DateFrom AND DateTo) 
  OR (''' + @DateTo + ''' BETWEEN DateFrom AND DateTo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since date formats can be different on each machine, I suggest you to use `DATEFROMPARTS(year, month, day)` instead of a literal string.

Use it like this:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime = DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 2, 9) ;
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime = DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 9, 20) ;
```